# Setting up a Raspberry Pi for Wi-Fi streaming video access from a kite outdoors

Tags: networking, wifi, streaming-video

I want to attach my already setup, video-streaming-capable Raspberry Pi web server setup to my kite and allow others in the close proximity to view the video via an IP address. There obviously won’t be any kind of commercial Wi-Fi service available so I assume I will have to create my own.

I tried making this all work using only one Raspberry Pi, but I think I need to use another Raspberry Pi.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: if you google for "raspberry access point" you will find plenty solutions for your problem.

Comment: I don't think you want a 2nd pi for this. You want a reasonably powerful wifi router with which you can set up a dedicated WLAN for this purpose. It could be on your current LAN as a subnet, meaning you can access it from there and control/limit access from there to your LAN. If your current router is powerful enough, you could use HEDMON's idea with the DMZ.  But you are going to have trouble getting powerful enough wifi on the pi kite for it to stay in range, which is why I think a dedicated router as close as possible (i.e., underneath, unless you have a tall building) is needed.

Comment: If you can find a decent USB wifi adapter with aimable antennea that can be used as an access point with the pi (make sure you check around about that before buying), you could go that route, but it will probably need a powered hub to be properly effective.  A hub + adapter of that sort will cost you almost as much as a decent router or AP and the latter will probably be much better at this.

Comment: You should not cross post a question to multiple sites in the SO network, when found one or more will be closed, As I said previously, rewording and reposting is not the correct way to handle a closed question. As you have been told by more than one moderator your question is off topic despite the fact that you are using a Pi. Turning your Pi into an access point is not specific to the Pi.

Comment: @SteveRobillard "Very cool and interesting project idea, but I believe it is better suited to the Raspberry Pi specific Stack Exchange site. –  JakeGould 16 hours ago"

What did I tell you? UHG! I'm done, this is so fraking stupid!!!

Comment: Just because a user of another site thinks it belongs here does not make it so. That is why it takes a moderator to migrate a question.

Comment: @SteveRobillard O M F G!! The very fact that the site itself is raspberrypi.stackexchange.com and I have a question about A RASPBERRY PI and the fact that it IS VERY SPECIFIC TO A PI  by the OS, the way it's programmed and it's use. These three things very much determine that any answers can ONLY ALSO BE PI RELATED. The fact that YOU cannot understand this and the fact you have such power to determine otherwise shows just how defunct this website truly is. You actually inhibit learning. Congratulations!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> allow others in the close proximity to view the video via an IP address

I guess the 'others' will be in the same LAN. I think the most easy solution is connect the RPi to some Access Point and share the wifi. If you want share it more 'far' I recommend review the security level of your project (iptables?) and connect the RPi with some router with DMZ. Also you will need some configuration for people from out your network can access to your stream, maybe you will need contact your ISP for more information.
If you want more specific solution, please provide more details.

Comment: That's the thing, there won't be an ISP of any kind. This will be out in an open field away from commercial wi-fi.

I'd like for people to just put in a IP address and view the streaming video like an IP camera but without the use of the web. But since my PI-webserver is setup to connect to a router, I'm thinking I need another Pi setup AS a router but I'm not sure hence the question.

Comment: If you RPi server is connect to the router and streaming, in theory the rest of clients in the same LAN can see the streaming

Comment: Found the perfect tutorial right [here](http://www.daveconroy.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-router-and-web-server/) Thanks all!